# PHPMyAdmin Setup Prompts for PHP 5.2+ after Install of PHP 5.3.8 on RHEL 5

Tags: php, redhat

I have a fresh RHEL 5 dedicated server that has just been updated with PHP 5.3.8.  When I browse http://my.ip.addy/setup to start the PHPMyAdmin setup, I receive a message stating PHP 5.2+ is required.  This is strange because the output of php -v show PHP 5.3.8.  Do we need a server or Apache restart?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php -v shows correct cause the command line version is returning it.

You need to restart apache for the correct version of the php module to get loaded. Apache loads all the module on startup and to stay fast and quick.. isn't going to go off and look at the filesystem each request for module updates.